# How to include webpack generated file in an HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a simple (traditional html,css,js) web project and I am intending to use [htmldiff-js library](https://github.com/dfoverdx/htmldiff-js/blob/master/dist/htmldiff.js) in my project.

I tried to download the htmldiff js from the GitHub and included directly in my HTML page using script tag. htmldiff js is compiled using webpack and contains import, module etc keywords.

When I open the HTML page in the browser, it throws an error. My question is how should I include this file - https://github.com/dfoverdx/htmldiff-js/blob/master/dist/htmldiff.js in my HTML page.

I have a very slight knowledge about webpack. I am not very sure about the correct solution here. I am going to read webpack in more details now but any pointers could be very helpful.

### Sample Code

#### index.html

```
<!-- HTML Diff JS -->
<script type="text/java" src="js/htmldiff.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

#### main.js

```
$('#compute-diff-button').click(function() {
  // diffUsingJS(v1Content, v2Content);
  var diffoutputdiv = document.getElementById('diffoutput');

  v1Content = "<button id=\"compute-diff-button\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-success\">Show Diff</button><p>Old Text</p>";
  v2Content = "<button id=\"compute-diff-button\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-success\">Show Diff</button><p class='text-center'>Some new text</p>";

  diffoutputdiv.innerHTML = Diff_HtmlDiff.execute(v1Content, v2Content);
});
```

Comment: You're more likely to get a good answer if you show the HTML used to include the script, so we're clear what you are doing, and show the error message received.

Comment: Thanks @joshp for the suggestion. I have added some code as an edit.

Comment: @sachinjain024 I see a typo in your code. Mimetype for htmldiff.js file should be "text/javascript" instead of "text/java".

Comment: Thanks @lazyvab for catching that. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a simple webpack project with an entry file which imports the `htmldiff-js` module and exposes on `window`, so you may access it from anywhere.

**index.js**

```
import HtmlDiff from 'htmldiff-js';
window.HtmlDiff = HtmlDiff;
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack'),
  path = require('path'),
  CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

var options = {
  entry: {
    htmldiff_generated: path.join(__dirname, 'index.js')
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['build'])
  ]
};

module.exports = options;
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --mode=development --display-error-details",
},
"dependencies": {
  "htmldiff-js": "^1.0.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
  "webpack": "^4.28.2",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="build/htmldiff_generated.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var v1Content = "<button id=\"compute-diff-button\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-success\">Show Diff</button><p>Old Text</p>";
    var v2Content = "<button id=\"compute-diff-button\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-success\">Show Diff</button><p class='text-center'>Some new text</p>";

    console.log(window.HtmlDiff.execute(v1Content, v2Content));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to use variables/functions other than `HtmlDiff`, expose in `index.js` in same fashion. It somewhat defeats the purpose of modular coding but your use-case should be achieved.

This is the generic strategy you may follow for other node modules too.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here's an alternate answer where you don't have to learn about Webpack.

If you change the [`webpack.config.js` line 16](https://github.com/dfoverdx/htmldiff-js/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L16) from `commonjs2` to `umd`, then run `npm run build`, you will get a `./dist/htmldiff.js` and `./dist/htmldiff.min.js` that you can use to bring into your `index.html` via a `<script src="..."></script>` tag.

I even uploaded the output to a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/therobinkim/21444d5a4cd89266ae0e6e16bced7764) and confirmed the demo code on the library's README is mostly working (pending some [small changes I made in a pull request](https://github.com/dfoverdx/htmldiff-js/pull/7)). Just remove the `import` statement on [line 39](https://github.com/dfoverdx/htmldiff-js/pull/7/files#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R39) in the example and use `HtmlDiff.default.execute(...)` instead of `HtmlDiff.execute(...)` on [line 46](https://github.com/dfoverdx/htmldiff-js/pull/7/files#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R46), and you'll be good to go!

Here's what the example in the README looks like when everything is working correctly. (Note that the third line shows you the HTML diff.)

[image: screenshot that shows working HTML diff example]

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] You probably don't want to use the suggestion I've listed here, because I realized that you are probably *not* trying to learn Webpack right now. I'll still leave it here for anybody else who ends up finding it beneficial, but it is likely overly complicated for what you're trying to do.

---

If you're going down the line of using Webpack yourself, first, run `npm install htmldiff-js` from anywhere within your project directory.

Then put the following line at the top of your JavaScript source file (eg, `./src/index.js`):

`import HtmlDiff from 'htmldiff-js';`

(from https://github.com/dfoverdx/htmldiff-js#javascript)

You will be able to use the variable called `HtmlDiff` from any file that you have already written `import HtmlDiff from 'htmldiff-js'`. For example, consider writing `console.log(HtmlDiff)` immediately after that line of code to see what appears in your browser's dev tools console.

When I was learning Webpack, I found it very helpful to read about the concept of `entry` and `output` at https://webpack.js.org/concepts/, then to do the `Installation` and `Getting Started` guides at https://webpack.js.org/guides/.

Good luck!